# Spring data: How to ignore field for relational database but not in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, jhipster, r2dbc

I have a problem with spring data and the `@Transient` annotation, in fact I have a class as follows:

```
@Table("example")
@Document(indexName = "example")
public class Example implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column("id")
  private Long id;
  
  @Transient
  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
  private User user;

  @Column("user_id")
  private Long userId;

  ...getter and setter 
}
```

I have a relational database and an elasticsearch.

In the database I just want to save the id and userId (and it works with this code).

but in elasticsearch I want to save the id and the user.

If I remove `@Transient` I get an error with R2dbc:

```
Nested entities are not supported in r2dbcEntityTemplate.insert
```

Does anyone know how to ignore it with R2dbc and take it into account with elasticsearch?