# Ignore property when persisting to ES, don't ignore when persisting to DB

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using spring-data(-elasticsearch), I want to persist a property to a PSQL DB but not to Elasticsearch, i.e. the opposite to this question: [Spring data: How to ignore field for relational database but not in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843478/spring-data-how-to-ignore-field-for-relational-database-but-not-in-elasticsearc)

In other words:

- when inserting this entity into ES, ignore `myDate`
- when inserting this entity into a DB, persist `myDate`

```java
@Entity
@Table("example")
@Document(indexName = "example")
public class Example implements Serializable {
  
  @Column(name = "my_date")
  @xyz
  private Instant myDate;

}
```

What should take the place of `@xyz` ? Is this possible at all?

- `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` excludes the property from both PSQL and ES
- `@JsonIgnore` does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same entity for multiple Spring Data modules. As you notice, this is an accident waiting to happen.

You could implement a `BeforeConvertCallback` (see the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.entity-callbacks)) and set the `myDate` property to null, so it won't be sent to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the word of advice and the workaround hack, which we can use until we restructured to use different entities.